# Why are DataTable values not showing on WPF DataGrid when column name contains '/'?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

The name of the second column in the DataTable below is "f/g", and when I run it I don't see the values in the second column on screen, why is that?

btw, when I change it into "f:g" it works, but "f[g" does not.

```
        DataTable resultDataTable = new DataTable();

        DataColumn id_column = new DataColumn();
        id_column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        id_column.ColumnName = "ID";
        id_column.ReadOnly = true;
        id_column.Unique = true;

        resultDataTable.Columns.Add(id_column);

        DataColumn f_column = new DataColumn();
        f_column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
        f_column.ColumnName = "f/g";
        f_column.ReadOnly = true;

        resultDataTable.Columns.Add(f_column);

        foreach (var entry in results.Results)
        {
            DataRow dr = resultDataTable.NewRow();
            dr[0] = entry.Key;
            dr[1] = entry.Value;
            resultDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultDataTable.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I don't know why its not working but I did find a way to workaround it by using the Column Caption property and implementing the AutoGeneratingColumn event in the DataGrid:

```
    private void ResultsDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var dGrid = (sender as DataGrid);
        if (dGrid == null) return;
        var view = dGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
        if (view == null) return;
        var table = view.Table;
        e.Column.Header = table.Columns[e.Column.Header as String].Caption;
    }
```

Basically it take whatever is in the Caption property and put it in the DataGrid Column Header even "f/g".

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I searched the web for hours and this is by far the best. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing
"f/g"

to

"f//g" or f[/]g

Escape the character

Comment: Tried it, its not working, column name showing to be "f//g" but no values. also "f[g" throws an exception.

Comment: Probably SQL then are you escaping the character in SQL? how are you getting data try f[/]g

Comment: The data itself is in a Dictionary<string,double> that I use to create the DataRows (see code above)

Comment: When I try "f[/]g" I get an exception -> "Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Syntax error in Binding.Path 'f[/]' ... 'g'.'."